# Show that if a topological space is metrizable then it is so in an infinite number of ways

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, metrizability

- Show that if a topological space is metrizable then it is so in an infinite number of ways.
- Show that a topological space $X$ is metrizable $\iff$ there exists a homeomorphism of $X$ onto a subspace of some metric space $Y$.

**My effort**:

**1**.Let $(X,\tau)$ be metrizable. Then there is a metric say $d$ on $X$ such that open sets in $(X,d)$ are same as that in $(X,\tau)$.

We know that if $d$ is a metric on $X$ then so is $kd$ for any $k(\in \Bbb R)>1$.Also $(X,d)$
and $(X,kd) $ generate the same collection of open sets.
whose proof runs as follows:

*Claim*: $U$ is open in $(X,d)\iff U$ is  open in $(X,kd)$

*Proof*:Let $U$ be open in $(X,d)$.Let $x\in U$ then for some $r>0;B_d(x,r)\subset U$ .Now choose $r_0=rk$.Then  I want to show that $B_{kd}(x,r_0)\subseteq U$.

let $z\in B_{kd}(x,r_0)\implies kd(z,x)<r_0\implies d(z,x)<\dfrac{r_0}{k}=r\implies z\in B(x,r)\subset U\implies B_{kd}(x,r_0)\subset U$

Conversely let $U$ is open in $(X,kd)$..Proceeding in the same way we find that $U$ is open in $(X,d)$

Thus $(X,kd)$ and $(X,d)$ are homeomorphic.QED.

Thus a topological space is metrizable in an infinite number of ways.

Is the solution correct?

**2**.For the second problem,I am unable to find the mapping which will give the homeomorphism.Please give some hints.

Comment: Non-Theorem: ​ There are infinitely-many additive identities on $\mathbb{R}$. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ "Proof:" ​ ​ ​ For any real number k, for all real numbers x, x+k-k=x+0=x=0+x=(k-k)+x. ​ Thus for any real number k, k-k is an additive identity on $\mathbb{R}$. ​ "Therefore" there are infinitely-many additive identities on $\mathbb{R}$. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: What is this ?@RickyDemer

Comment: Part two can be done trivially. If the homeomorphism exists, you're metrizable. If $X$ is metrizable, let $X = Y$. Then there exists a trivial homeomorphism from $X$ to $Y$, namely the identity, and $Y$ is a subspace of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you very much @AJY; well can you say something regarding my first problem

Comment: Oh, my apologies. Yes, so long as you can show $(X, kd)$ induces the same topology, you are good to go.

Comment: @S.Bandopadhaya : ​ I was giving an illustration of why your argument for 1. isn't quite enough. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer;I have given a proof of the claim

Comment: @AJY; Please check my proof

Comment: ... that for all positive real numbers $k$, $d$ and $kd$ generate the same collection of open sets. ​ However, it doesn't follow that $X$ is metrizable "in an infinite number of ways.". ​ (See my "proof" of a false claim.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: For the first one you probably want to assume the space is not the empty set.

Comment: Looks good @S.Bandopadhaya

Comment: I am unable to understand your point@RickyDemer; maybe something extraordinary but sorry for that

Comment: @S.Bandopadhaya : ​ ​ ​ Do you understand why the Non-Theorem I gave is false? ​ If yes, do you understand why the "Proof" of it doesn't work? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky: Like the OP, I fail to see its relevance.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:If d is a metric that induces the topology on X then so does the metric f(d),
where f is any strictly increasing, real-valued function defined on the non-negative reals such that 
f(0) = 0 and f(a+b) <= f(a) + f(b) for all a,b >= 0.

[If d is a metric, then so is k*d for any positive k, and it still induces the same topology. 
I'm sure you can find other modifications of d that remains a metric (don't forget to show that it still induces the same topology). Try this one: d/(1+d) (and all positive multiples of it), use the mean value theorem to show that it satisfies the triangle inequality.]